# What are commonly used words that mean "not working" or "not working as intended"?

Tags: word-choice

Would appreciate assistance regarding words or phrases that mean **not working** or **not working properly** that I should look up and can use, especially in the contexts below:

1. *The website shows an error message every time I open it; it's ________*
2. *You can't use the car because it's ________*
3. *The lights at the airport cannot be turned on because they are _______*

Comment: The phrase used in the question, "not working," might be one of the most flexible and universally appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

> A thesaurus can be your friend here.

Indeed, the idea of something not working (propely) can be expressed is different ways, so just to keep the ball rolling, I suggest trying these:

- *The website shows an error message every time I open it; it's malfunctioning.*
- *You can't use the car because it's out of order.*
- *The lights at the airport cannot be turned on because they are not functioning.*

Comment: _Faulty_ would cover all three situations.

Answer (score 0):

A thesaurus can be your friend here. Different nouns can sound better to the native ear with different descriptions of the type of failure. For example:

1. The website shows an error message every time I open it; it's *unreachable*.
2. You can't use the car because it's [*broken down* | *inoperable*].
3. The lights at the airport cannot be turned on because they are *out of order*.

Many of these words and phrases are roughly synonymous with *not working*, but each has a slightly different connotation and may not sound natural or convey the intended meaning when paired incorrectly. For example, you'd be unlike to say that "lights are unreachable" unless they are physically out of reach. *Inoperable* is probably the only word that potentially fits all three of your examples, but an unreachable page doesn't mean the whole web site is inoperative, so again would have to say context matters.